How to solve: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory , open vite.config.js
I am having a problem when running
npm run dev.

I get the following error:
failed to load config from C:\Users\rober\Documents\GitHub\SPHere-FrontEnd-React\vite.config.js
error when starting dev server:
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\rober\Documents\GitHub\SPHere-FrontEnd-React\vite.config.js.timestamp-1716474665024-cb2def9165217.mjs'

Previously, it wouldn't even let me install node_modules because it got stuck at idealTree. Finally, after looking for solutions, I decided to downgrade the Node version to 18, and it worked. However, then I got the following error, and it was working fine yesterday. This morning, when I tried to run it, I got the error. I have already tried disabling IPv6 on Windows, deleting package-lock.json and node_modules, and reinstalling, but I get the same error. It's as if temporary files are being created and it tries to find them. If I rename the file to the temporary one it was looking for, the error goes away, but the application doesn't work. I don't know what else to do. If anyone knows how to fix it, I would appreciate your help.
I also tried changing the extension from .js to .mjs and it didn't work.
Another thing I have tried is installing Vite 4.2.2 and its React plugin version 1.0.0, but it didn't work.
If I rename the file to the one it tries to find, I get this error:
Re-optimizing dependencies because lockfile has changed error when starting dev server: Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Users\rober\Documents\GitHub\SPHere-FrontEnd-React\node_modules\.vite\deps\@reduxjs_toolkit.js'
However, even if I fix this error, I don't think it will work. The one I want to fix is the ENOENT error.
I managed to fix the last error by deleting the .vite folder, and now it seems to run on localhost, but it keeps loading infinitely and does nothing.
The error lies in the fact that the -timestamp.mjs file does not exist, and it tries to load the configuration from a non-existent file instead of loading it from vite.config.js.
I tried creating a new project from scratch and copying the files, but when I run npm run dev, I get the same error, so it's not an issue with the project.
